# Accessing array elements loaded in Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting a set of comma separated string from database through an Ajax call which looks like

```
b-819-0,b-819-1,b-819-2
```

I tried to load it into an array using

```
let imgNames = []; 
imgNames.push(obj[i]['indicators'].split(','));
```

now loging the array looks ok as:

[image]

but when I try to access the elements in a loop like

```
 for (let i = 0; i <2; i++) { 
  inx += '<li class="list-inline-item"> <div class="product" data-fname="'+imgNames[i]+'"></div></li>';
  }
```

it is dumping all element of array in only first `fname` ! and adding `undefined` to orthers. Again as you can see I have already 3 elements in the `imgNames` array!

Why is this happening and how I can fix this?

Comment: I think you are looking for [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax): `imgNames.push(...obj[i]['indicators'].split(','));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imgNames is an array with only one element, the comma splitted array.

This happens because you're pushing `obj[i]['indicators'].split(',')` into the empty imgNames array.

Your code should be:

```
let tuples = obj[i]['indicators'].split(',')
tuples.forEach(imgNames.push)
```

Assuming that imgNames is not empty

If not, then simply do `let imgNames = obj[i]['indicators'].split(',')`

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing an array in the first element

### use `concat` instead of `push`

```
imgNames.concat(obj[i]['indicators'].split(','));
```

Comment: You are missing the assignment, back to `imageNames = imageNames.concat(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to add each item to the array so you don't have an array of arrays but instead an array of strings.

```
let imagNames = ['img-1', 'img-2']
imgNames.push(...obj[i]['indicators'].split(','))
```

Will result in the following:

```
imageNames = ['img-1', 'img-2', 'b-819-0', 'b-819-1', 'b-819-2']
```

Instead of resulting in:

```
imageNames = [
  'img-1', 'img-2',
  ['b-819-0', 'b-819-1', 'b-819-2']
]
```